# Triggering a Twilio Flow through Zapier Webhook but it is not continuing past the first widget

Tags: twilio, zapier, twilio-flow

So I am trying to get Zapier to trigger a Twilio Flow via the webhook action. The thing is is that I am having difficulty getting Twilio to continue on in the flow after sending the first step. I am not sure what I am missing but this is what I have set up.

For Zapier this is my webhook setup to try and trigger the Twilio flow. The step before this one allows Twilio to send a text to the person, but then the flow is suppose to trigger to allow the person to respond accordingly to the text messages and prompts. Here is how the webhook is filled out.

URL - Twilio REST API url

To - To the phone number that is going to be receiving the text messages

From - The Twilio phone number itself

Basic Auth - The Twilio Account SID and Auth Token

[Zapier zap step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKnXo.png)

As for Twilio itself is set up like this. The REST API is connected to the first step which is suppose to send a text and then wait for a response. Then it is to hit the next step which is looking for a certain response before going to either path I have it set up as.

[Twilio Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/605jX.png)

When this flow is activated it does to the yes_no_start widget so the person does receive a text and a session is started. But once someone tries to respond to the text nothing else happens so I am not sure if I am missing a step or what. The Twilio number is not connected to any service and I have the messages set up that when a message comes in it will respond with that particular flow, but it will won't go past the first widget.

Comment: This looks all good at first sight. It would be interesting to know if you see the incoming message (a) in the messaging monitor in the console and (b) if it shows up in the Studio log flow.

Comment: Looking at the log it does appear that it triggers but it doesn't continue on after someone responds, I've added a screenshot just in case. https://imgur.com/a/C0rSEwb

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem now, you are checking for the `trigger.message.body` in the split widget: [image]

But this is actually not right as you want to check the response of the "Send and Wait" widget. So this means you need check for this variable instead `widgets.yes_no_start.outbound.Body`.